# Using Exclusion Script in Triggered Email Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, triggered-send

I have been trying to use exclusion script to exclude customers from receiving emails triggered from API using triggered send.

The process followed is as below :

1. Create a standard DE `Test_Opt_Out_List` with the excluded customers ( containing subscriberkey and emailaddress fields ).
2. In the triggered send definition have specified the following code :

   `ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Test_Opt_Out_List","SubscriberKey",_subscriberkey))>0`
3. Each time the API is triggered with the same subscriber key present in Test_Opt_Out_List, the record is getting added to the Triggered DE and email is being sent.

Can you please let me know if I am missing anything here ? I also tried creating the DE with Domain Exclusion template and used the same exclusion script , I am still receiving the emails.

Answer (score 1):

The above works with standard DE , I was saving the changes made in Triggered send and starting the triggered send definition , missed the step after save where we need to publish the changes.

The above functionality seems working fine once the publish changes is clicked and Triggered send definition is started.

Thanks.